# Good amp for bookshelf 6 ohm speakers

Tags: audio, amplifiers

I'm new to speaker amplifiers and have been reading up on them. Basically, I need an amp that preferably can deliver about 30 wattsx2 at 6 ohms, has treble&bass controls, and has a nice sound quality. Budget tops out at about 50 dollars if it's really worth it.

If there's any other things you think are important for such an amp, feel free to mention them and look for an amp with that too. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure about the $50 limit.  If you have thrift shops in your area, those can be a really good place to look for things first.  most of my speakers for my 5.1 system are used, 1970s to 1980s era (back when they made stuff to last).   But as far as newer systems.....this is gonna take some time searching......I'll need coffee.